# Constraints getting effected when changing the size class?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I have a view controller on storyboard.I want different UI for different screen sizes for i decided to use concept of size classes.I am able to design the UI in different size classes.But the issue is when i change the size class in storyboard & again switch to old size class then the constraints are not aligned properly they are getting effected whenever i switch between different size classes.So i again have to arrange the constraints so please tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I see the issue when the constraints are added on UITableViewCell contetView subViews... It'll generate a warning but will run as expected. No cure of this pain as of now.

Comment: I am not using table but this issue is on all ui controls@RohitKumar

Comment: For me this happens only in UITableViewCell.

Comment: is it xcode bug or something?

Comment: Seems like since I didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an approach to Autolayout and Size classes:

Create a new project and recreate an environment similar to your request and work with auto layout and size classes, so you can see how it works and later on apply it to your project.

From the storyboard, take a look at the layouts bar (I don't know the technical name). It is the blue bar at the bottom of the screen where it says "wAny hAny"

This layout will allow you to add constraints for a general purpose. That is not your case, but anyway, add the generic values to your all your objects: i.e: top space, width, etc. Until you see all clear, in blue without auto layout warnings.

Now click on wCompact-hAny (see the text when you click there: It says for iphone 3.5,4, 4.7 layouts in portrait mode).

Open the Assistant editor and find "Preview", so you will see what the screen is going to look like when running on the device. At this point you should have half screen with your storyboard and half screen with the preview mode.

Move and resize your objects as required. Try to Update constraints from the blue layout bar on the bottom: Last right icon "Resolve Autolayout issues". Select update constraints.

It should fix the constraints for your iphone when it is in portrait mode (wCompact-hAny) but if you see any red line there is something wrong, let me explain:

From the general layout (wAny-hAny) you should SET general constraints:i.E. I want a text label that has a space fixed to the left, so its constraint is something like: left space to container=5, then when you have your device specifically in portrait mode and you want that label on the right side of the screen and set 'right space to container'=5, there is a complain. Xcode will not know what to do as it has constraints for that label to the left and to the right...

With wAny-hAny you are setting general constraints and when you set a new layout in wCompact-wAny the size class inherits those values.

Solution? From the child layout class, Delete the disappointing constraint and add the necessary ones so when the device is in this mode (portrait) it knows how to display the objects.

Weird? it is.
Now go to wAny-wCompact, and then move your label or whatever to a different position. Don't forget to see how it changes in the preview screen!

If at some point you get lost, delete all constraints in all the layout modes and try again until you understand how it works. I wish I could be more specific or more helpful but it is quite difficult to explain. Best of luck!

Comment: you said right but you didn't understand my problem.Once i have set the constraints for one layout(iPhone portrait) then i when i change the screen to landscape mode in xcode constraints are getting effected which i don't want.@MLBDG

Comment: @deepakkumar did u get solution for ur problem ??. even im facing same issue

Comment: no i had to use new constraints for different size class. if you get solution then post answer